# Multiple asynctasks reusing progressbar

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have done my research very thoroughly with no actual result so here I am.

I have a horizontal ProgressBar in my app which I use to indicate a progress in file upload. When I upload a whole directory though, I am trying to make it show progress of single files uploaded at the time. I use asynctasks with a FixedThreadPool(1). The thing is, that only the first task triggers the progressbar.

The method in main activity:

```
uploadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
private void upload() throws DropboxException, IOException {
                if(isDir){
                    DataDir dir = new DataDir(file);
                    List<File> files = dir.getFileList();

                    for(File item : files){
                        Upload upload = new Upload(getActivity(), dropbox, "/Apps/Sink/", item, bar);
                        upload.executeOnExecutor(uploadExecutor);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Upload upload = new Upload(getActivity(), dropbox, "/Apps/Sink/", file, bar);
                    upload.executeOnExecutor(uploadExecutor);
                }
            }
```

Upload is a class that implements AsyncTask and handles the upload of the file.

When created, the instance of the class sets the bar to be visible and in OnPostExecute() sets it to be invisible

---

### EDIT

Adding the Upload class.

```
 public Upload(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api, String dropboxPath,
                  File file, ProgressBar mBar) {

    this.mBar = mBar;
    mBar.setProgress(0);
    mBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

@Override protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
    try {
        // By creating a request, we get a handle to the putFile operation,
        // so we can cancel it later if we want to
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
        String path = mPath + mFile.getName();
        mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(),
                new ProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public long progressInterval() {
                        // Update the progress bar every half-second or so
                        return 500;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                        publishProgress(bytes);
                    }
                });

        if (mRequest != null) {
            mRequest.upload();
            return true;
        }


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... progress) {
    int percent = (int)(100.0*(double)progress[0]/mFileLen + 0.5);
    //mDialog.setProgress(percent);
    mBar.setProgress(percent);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if (result) {
        showToast("File successfully uploaded");
    } else {
        showToast(mErrorMsg);
    }
    mBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

### EDIT

I resolved the issue by moving the for cycle into the upload class.
Very similar approach [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726498/android-asynctask-upload-multiple-files-to-dropbox)

Answer (score 1):

In your Upload class you can implement the method for AsynkTak that checks for progress status changes

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) { /*Your code*/ }

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29)

Comment: Thanks, I already did that of course. The thing is, that it does show the bar only when the first file is uploading. Post edited

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you initialize one AsyncTask per file and give each of them a reference to the same ProgressBar.

What happens is, you loop through the files and init the AsyncTasks. Now if the first task finishes the bar will be set to invisible. The following tasks aren't able to set it visible again with your current setup.

You can try to set the bar visible in [onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) of the AsyncTask, because this one will be invoked before doInBackground() kicks in. Or you can trigger the onProgreesUpdate() at the beginning of doInBackground() to make it visible there.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried both, but always ended with an exception.

"ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: Can you show the code you tried? Don't update the view directly in the doInBackground().

Comment: I just moved the SetVisibility to OnProgressUpdate and called OnProgressUpdate in the beginning of doInBackground.